# Windows server 2008 asp.net timeout

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, asp.net, timeout, web-services

I developed a simple asp.net webservice that we install in our customers servers in order they can use a mobile app.

I tested the webservice on a windows server 2012 and all was ok. Then I moved to the customer server who has a windows server 2008 r2, I activated IIS, created the new aplication pool enabling 32b apps, mounted the aplication and tried on localhost and all was ok.

It works either on

```
localhost/service/someservice.asmx
```

or

```
127.0.0.1/service/someservice.asmx
```

But it doesn't work on

```
customer.dyndns.org/service/someservice.asmx
```

or

```
xx.xx.xx.xx/service/someservice.asmx
```

giving me connection timeout errors.

- I increased the time out on the web.config
- I tried a ping to customer.dyndns.org and it was ok
- I also tried go to    customer.dyndns.org/emptyfile.txt just to try
  it wasn't a "size" problem.
- I check the firewall and it has the permision for 80 port on    http

So... I don't know what else I can do...

We have some webservice like this one working on other servers with windows server 2003, 2008 and 2012 and they work without problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trys we noticed that telnet conection to the webservice was failing. We check the router config and the port 80 was blocked.